# How to stub the context manager close method in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest, contextmanager

I need to do some operations that did not work well using the builtin mock module.
Then I decided to mock this by myself, using:

```
import builtins
import io
from unittest import mock
import my_module

builtins.open = mock.Mock()
builtins.open.return_value = io.StringIO()
builtins.open.return_value.__exit__ = lambda a, b, c, d: None 
my_module.f('foo')
builtins.open.return_value.seek(0)
txt = builtins.open.return_value.read()
print(txt)
```

While, in my_module.py:

```
def f(fname):
   with open(fname) as handle:
       g(handle)

def g(fhandle):
    fhandle.write('bar')
```

Using this approach, I get a ValueError, which message is "I/O operation on closed file". I expected the lambda to work to stub the **exit** method, why does not it work? How can I stub it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using mocks "mock_open" by any chance? This is some code I used a while back, that I believe should work. Let me know if this helps you:

```
@mock.patch('__builtin__.open', new_callable=mock_open())
def test_foo(self, m_open):
    self.foo()

    m_open.assert_called_once_with("something", 'w')
    m_open().__enter__().write.assert_called_once_with("stuff")
```

Here is some more documentation on [mock_open](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#mock-open)

Comment: Yes, I tried. But I want to have access to the content, not only using assert_called_once_with. I also noticed that mock_open was not going deep into the stack.

Comment: Have you considered maybe using a temporary folder context? That way you can just test the open in a temp space and the exit on the tempfolder will then just remove everything.

Comment: I don't like the idea of accessing the filesystem for unittesting, disk usage removes the isolation of a test. In addition to that, there should be a simple way of treating a file as a StringIO.

Comment: Yes, understandably. What is it you are trying to test exactly? I'm sorry if I missed this in your explanation. I didn't quite catch that part.

Comment: I want to access whatever was written into the file, I changed the code sample to get closer to the one I have. In this case, there is only one write instruction, but there may be more instructions. And I want to assert the final value that was written.